# capture image from camera and crop not working

Tags: android, camera, crop

here is my camera intent.

```
            File file = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
            file.mkdirs();
            File output = new File(file, "profile_image");
            if (output.exists()) {
                output.delete();
            }
            Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output);
            startActivityForResult(captureIntent, PublicValues.IMAGE_FROM_CAMERA);
```

in onActivityresult

```
if (requestCode == PublicValues.IMAGE_FROM_CAMERA) { 

                if (mPhotoUri != null) {
                    performCrop(mPhotoUri);
                } else {
                    pictureUri = data.getData();
                    performCrop(pictureUri);
                }
```

and crop intent

```
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true"); // set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);  // indicate aspect of desired crop(ratio)
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true); // retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", profileImage.getWidth());   // indicate output X and Y
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", profileImage.getHeight());

            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PublicValues.IMAGE_CROP);
```

it works fine with API 19 device but crashes in Marshmallow device.

crash report is like this:-

```
Caused by android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20170721-WA0014.jpg exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed (StrictMode.java:1813)
android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed (Uri.java:2360)
android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess (Intent.java:8981)
android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess (Intent.java:8942)
android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity (Instrumentation.java:1583)
android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:4228)
android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult (BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult (FragmentActivity.java:79)
```

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Comment: @AjilO. see my edit

Comment: all permissions are given to your app , right ??

Comment: @GaganDeep yup.CAMERA,READ and WRITE External storage

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/6891637) will solve your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed)

Comment: Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`. There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you.i think it is the point

Answer (score 3):

use Gradle :

```
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
```

and try this:

```
private void performCrop(Uri imageUri) {
    CropImage.activity(imageUri)
            .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
            .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.RECTANGLE)
            .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
            .setMultiTouchEnabled(true)
            .start(this);
}
```

Comment: implement this gradle file in your project and write this method in your class, after then call this performCrop() method with parameter of imageUri which you want to get cropped.

Comment: Just a little addition to Stuti Kasliwal's answer. To make it work, you will need to add `<activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"/>` to the AndroidManifest. You'll also have to handle saving and passing the image after the crop.