# Cropping captured image is blur in android

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, crop, onactivityresult

Hi basically I am selecting image form gallery  or capture from camera and cropping it. If I crop image  which is selected from gallery is no blur its fine but if I crop captured images means its getting blur.

To start camera I have used

```
private void cameraIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

    }
```

and in camera `onActivityResult`

```
private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        crop(getImageUri(csActivity,bm));

    }
```

This is for crop image

```
private void crop(Uri uri)
    {
        final Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setData(uri);
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 96);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 96);
        intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CROP);
    }
```

and in crop result I have used

```
private void onCropImg(Intent data)
    {
        Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, stream);

        Uri tempUri = getImageUri(csActivity,bm);

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
        File destination = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));

        csProfileImg.setImageBitmap(bm);

        uploadProfileImg(destination);
        }
```

and to `getImageUri`

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library to crop image, that would give proper results along with the image quality. use: `compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'`

And for more you can visit this page: [check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279179/capture-image-from-camera-and-crop-not-working/45281414#45281414)

Answer (score 0):

This answer will helps others to resolve issue on capture photo from camera which gives a blur image while cropping.

By adding library in `build.gradle` :

```
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
```

Adding Permission on `Manifest` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

*CameraActivity.java :*

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

    private CropImageView mCropImageView;
    private CircleImageView imVCature_pic;
    private Uri mCropImageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        mCropImageView = (CropImageView)  findViewById(R.id.CropImageView);
        imVCature_pic = (CircleImageView)  findViewById(R.id.imVCature_pic);
    }

    /**
     * On load image button click, start pick image chooser activity.
     */
    public void onLoadImageClick(View view) {
        startActivityForResult(getPickImageChooserIntent(), 200);
    }

    /**
     * Crop the image and set it back to the  cropping view.
     */
    public void onCropImageClick(View view) {
        Bitmap cropped =  mCropImageView.getCroppedImage(500, 500);
        if (cropped != null)
            imVCature_pic.setImageBitmap(cropped);
            //mCropImageView.setImageBitmap(cropped);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int  requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri imageUri =  getPickImageResultUri(data);

            // For API >= 23 we need to check specifically that we have permissions to read external storage,
            // but we don't know if we need to for the URI so the simplest is to try open the stream and see if we get error.
            boolean requirePermissions = false;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                    checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    isUriRequiresPermissions(imageUri)) {

                // request permissions and handle the result in onRequestPermissionsResult()
                requirePermissions = true;
                mCropImageUri = imageUri;
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
            }

            if (!requirePermissions) {
                mCropImageView.setImageUriAsync(imageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if (mCropImageUri != null && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mCropImageView.setImageUriAsync(mCropImageUri);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Required permissions are not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a chooser intent to select the  source to get image from.<br/>
     * The source can be camera's  (ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) or gallery's (ACTION_GET_CONTENT).<br/>
     * All possible sources are added to the  intent chooser.
     */
    public Intent getPickImageChooserIntent() {

// Determine Uri of camera image to  save.
        Uri outputFileUri =  getCaptureImageOutputUri();

        List<Intent> allIntents = new ArrayList<>();
        PackageManager packageManager =  getPackageManager();

// collect all camera intents
        Intent captureIntent = new  Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        List<ResolveInfo> listCam =  packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
            Intent intent = new  Intent(captureIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
            if (outputFileUri != null) {
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            }
            allIntents.add(intent);
        }

// collect all gallery intents
        Intent galleryIntent = new  Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        List<ResolveInfo> listGallery =  packageManager.queryIntentActivities(galleryIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo res : listGallery) {
            Intent intent = new  Intent(galleryIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new  ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
            allIntents.add(intent);
        }

// the main intent is the last in the  list (fucking android) so pickup the useless one
        Intent mainIntent =  allIntents.get(allIntents.size() - 1);
        for (Intent intent : allIntents) {
            if  (intent.getComponent().getClassName().equals("com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity"))  {
                mainIntent = intent;
                break;
            }
        }
        allIntents.remove(mainIntent);

// Create a chooser from the main  intent
        Intent chooserIntent =  Intent.createChooser(mainIntent, "Select source");

// Add all other intents
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,  allIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[allIntents.size()]));

        return chooserIntent;
    }

    /**
     * Get URI to image received from capture  by camera.
     */
    private Uri getCaptureImageOutputUri() {
        Uri outputFileUri = null;
        File getImage = getExternalCacheDir();
        if (getImage != null) {
            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new  File(getImage.getPath(), "pickImageResult.jpeg"));
        }
        return outputFileUri;
    }

    /**
     * Get the URI of the selected image from  {@link #getPickImageChooserIntent()}.<br/>
     * Will return the correct URI for camera  and gallery image.
     *
     * @param data the returned data of the  activity result
     */
    public Uri getPickImageResultUri(Intent  data) {
        boolean isCamera = true;
        if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            String action = data.getAction();
            isCamera = action != null  && action.equals(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
        return isCamera ?  getCaptureImageOutputUri() : data.getData();
    }

    /**
     * Test if we can open the given Android URI to test if permission required error is thrown.<br>
     */
    public boolean isUriRequiresPermissions(Uri uri) {
        try {
            ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
            InputStream stream = resolver.openInputStream(uri);
            stream.close();
            return false;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof Exception) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

*activity_camera.xml :*

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onLoadImageClick"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="Load Image" />

    <com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView
        android:id="@+id/CropImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onCropImageClick"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="Crop Image" />

</LinearLayout>
```