# Captured image displays blur

Tags: android, camera, android-camera-intent, photoeditorsdk

I am trying to capture image from camera but it come out to be blur. Below is the code that I am using.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

  Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
  mPhotoEditorView.getSource().setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
```

Comment: Because It is only return thumbnail.

Comment: Try this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56537178/9844646

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a blurry image appear in a simple android camera app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121729/why-does-a-blurry-image-appear-in-a-simple-android-camera-app)

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.

Comment: @Kaveri Patel Su issue che?

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

Above method only provides thumbnail.

To save the full-size Photo you should follow this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPath).

Add this permission in your manifest.

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Create a File. In this, we will save the image:

```
String currentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Now, you can invoke capture Intent like this:

```
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ...
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                                  "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                                                  photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

Add `FileProvider` in your Manifest file

```
<application>
   ...
   <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
    ...
</application>
```

Create **res/xml/file_paths.xml** file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Here you go, you have saved a full-size image to the file you had created.

**Bonus:** You should always scale your image before using it in an ImageView, this will help you optimize your app's Memory usage.

```
private void setPic() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = imageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = imageView.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code to resolve blur issue

```
thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scale bitmap with your desired height and width high value  to get more clearity.

first you have to get path from your intent data uri.

```
private String getpath(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String filePath = null;
    try {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null,
                null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int dataColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                filePath = cursor.getString(dataColumn);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

    }
    return filePath;
}
```

then use this code to get your image bitmap

```
public static Bitmap scaleImage(String p_path, int p_reqHeight, int p_reqWidth) throws Throwable {
    Bitmap m_bitMap = null;

    File m_file = new File(p_path);
    if (m_file.exists()) {
        BitmapFactory.Options m_bitMapFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        m_bitMapFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(m_file.getPath(), m_bitMapFactoryOptions);
        m_bitMapFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(m_bitMapFactoryOptions, p_reqHeight, p_reqWidth);
        m_bitMapFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        m_bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(m_file.getPath(), m_bitMapFactoryOptions);
    } else {
        throw new Throwable(p_path + " not found or not a valid image");
    }
    return m_bitMap;
}
```